# Rails: how to retrieve the params for child objects in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, parameters

I have a wizard situation where I create a Parent object, and then build a form with 2 nested children.

The parameters that get submitted look like this:

```
Parameters: {"room"=>
{"parents_attributes"=>
{"0"=>{"name"=>"r2", "phone"=>"07443107986"},
 "1"=>{"name"=>"", "phone"=>""}}},
 "commit"=>"Go!", "id"=>"step03"}
```

(the commit and id are from the wicked wizard step)

If the user refreshes the page, the id's for these children change and the parameters look like this:

```
Parameters: {"room"=>
{"parents_attributes"=>
{"1"=>{"name"=>"r2", "phone"=>"07443107986"},
 "2"=>{"name"=>"", "phone"=>""}}},
 "commit"=>"Go!", "id"=>"step03"}
```

Since the id's are generated by the fields_for.

My controller code retrieves the data like this (the room is saved in the session on a previous step):

```
    @room = Room.find(session[:room_id])
    @room.parents.build(room_params[:parents_attributes]['0'])
    @room.parents.build(room_params[:parents_attributes]['1'])
```

This obviously only works if the user does not refresh the page. Also, if validations fire the id's of the children change too.

What is a better way to retrieve these parent_attributes from the params hash?

**EDIT**

In the wizard step, the child objects are built like this:

```
when :step03
  @room = Room.find(session[:room_id])
  2.times{ @room.parents.build }
```

Comment: `room_params[:parents_attributes].each {|k,_| @room.parents.build(room_params[:parents_attributes][k])}` - can you do something like this where you would be extracting hash keys dynamically ?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to do this if you're using `nested_attributes` in your parent model. Have you tried that approach?

Comment: @Anthony E yes, I am using nested attributes

Comment: Why do you need to modify the params hash if you're using nested attributes? Does `Room.create(room_params)` not work?

Comment: @AnthonyE that doesn't work because the parent object (room) is not in the form - notice there is no room id submitted in the params, so it does not know which room to build

Comment: @dkp That worked! Please put it as the answer and I will mark it.

Comment: @rmcsharry i have added my answer.glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following to extract hash keys dynamically:

```
room_params[:parents_attributes].each {|k,_| @room.parents.build(room_params[:parents_attributes][k])}
```